# copy of object (JAVA)

Tags: java, object

I am trying to make a copy of an object to make some tests on it without affecting the original object. I made this copy() function but the original object is still affected.

Inside the class "I" I have this copy function:

```
@Override
public Piece copy() {
    I newPiece = new I(blocks[0], blocks[1], blocks[2], blocks[3]);
    newPiece.STATUS = this.STATUS;
    newPiece.FORM = this.FORM;
    return newPiece;
}
```

and I try to make a copy like this:

```
Piece rotated = piece.copy();
rotated.changeForm();
```

Class "I" is a subclass of the abstract class Piece with the abstract method copy(). when I do the changeForm() in the copied object it affects the original one too.

**SOLVED**

the Block objects were passed as reference too so I needed to add a copy() method even for the type Block. Code changed this way:

```
    @Override
public Piece copy() {
    I newPiece=new I(blocks[0].copy(),blocks[1].copy(),blocks[2].copy(),blocks[3].copy());
    newPiece.STATUS=this.STATUS;
    newPiece.FORM=this.FORM;
    return newPiece;
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `blocks`?

Comment: I the content of blocks are reference types, you have to copy them too.

Comment: if you make a copy by setting objects from the original as properties from the copy, making changes to those same properties will affect the properties from the original and the copy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy an object in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every type of Piece attributes or fields that is not a primitive type should be copied too.
So the values of `STATUS`, `blocks[1], blocks[2], blocks[3]` and `FORM`.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If the contents of blocks are reference types, you will also have to copy them.

Alternatively you could just make a new constructor for Piece and use it.

```
Piece newPiece = new Piece(oldPiece.thing1(), oldPiece.thing2().....);
```

Answer (score 2):

This  is the problem, in your copy constructor:

`Piece rotated=piece.copy();`

That's just copying the reference to the Piece. Both objects will still refer to the same object.

You can use:

`Piece rotated = new Piece(piece.copy());`

Answer (score 2):

You're not changing the new object, you're changing its contents. Unfortunately, the original object has *the same contents*, so it *appears* as though you had done something to the original object.

You have made what is called a **shallow copy**. It would appear that you need to make a **deep copy**, which involves making copies of the contents of the original object. In your case, you need to make a copy of `blocks[0]`, `blocks[1]`, etc.

The question that may haunt you is how deep *that* copy must be. You will no doubt find out, but you may have to go deeper than it would appear at first.

Answer (score 1):

As previous authors mention you should make a deep copy of object, but with your code you're only making a shallow copy.

The fastest and easiest way to deep copy an object in java is to `serialize`() it and `deserialize`().

Assuming all your classes implement java.io.Serializable interface:

```
public static <T extends Serializable> T copy(T orig) {

    T obj = null;
    try {
        // Write the object out to a byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(orig);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        // Make an input stream from the byte array and read
        // a copy of the object back in.
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));
        obj = (T) in.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```